# generate xml with key/value structure using for xml

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to generate this

```
<Mail>
  <Field key="SenderName" value="someone" />
  <Field key="RecipientName" value="someone else" />
<Mail/>
<Mail>
  <Field key="SenderName" value="another someone" />
  <Field key="RecipientName" value="another someone else" />
<Mail/>
```

heres the test data

```
declare @tab table (SenderName varchar(255), RecipientName varchar(255))
insert @tab
select 'someone' , 'someone else' union 
select 'another someone' , 'another someone else'
```

I have tried various things with for xml path but I cant work out how to tell declare that I want a new element of the same name after recipient name.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @tab table (SenderName varchar(255), RecipientName varchar(255))
insert @tab
select 'someone' , 'someone else' union 
select 'another someone' , 'another someone else' 

select (select 'SenderName' as "@key",
                SenderName  as "@value"
        for xml path('Field'), type),
       (select 'RecipientName' as "@key",
                RecipientName  as "@value"
        for xml path('Field'), type) 
from @tab
for xml path('Mail')
```